# j2me form (on android)

Tags: android, forms, java-me, menu

Im running an j2me app on android.
Im aware that form runs in fullscreen, but since on android all actions are in menu i would like to get rid of the action buttons on form.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write a native Android app. Running J2ME apps on Android is never a good idea:

- they are not native, so they won't "feel right"
- you will not be able to use a lot of the goodies the platform offers you (such as the menu button)
- the interface will most probably look a bit bodged
- J2ME apps are harder to debug
- you might even run into performance issues

Try porting your J2ME app to the Android SDK. Keep only the non-interface stuff (any calculations, api libs, etc.) and rewrite the interface stuff using the Android SDK. It's a bit more work, but it will be completely worth it.

Comment: Thanx for your anwser. I have tried that. But i found limitations, as some libs in Android are missing. I have core libs, j2me libs and client. I tried to port core and j2me libs but i have tons of errors...

Answer (score 0):

You can use an automatic conversion tool from J2ME to Android. UpOnTek provides an automatic conversion tool, which includes optimization tips for the app. Take a look at www.UpOnTek.com or contact michal.geva@UpOnTek.com for more details.

Comment: You might want to [read this faq entry about self-promotion.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limit-to-self-promotion-in-answers/59302#59302)